# Error: Getting "non-static variable ... cannot be referenced" when trying to fill and array with random numbers

Tags: arrays, random, static, syntax-error, non-static

I'm trying to convert an array of 30 elements into an array of 30 random numbers but I keep receiving the error "Non-static variable rand cannot be referenced in a static context" on the "numbers[counter] = randomInt;"
I'm fairly new at this and I've looked around for similar questions and solutions but everything I found was unclear.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int length = 30;
    int numbers[] = new int[length];
    int randomInt;
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++)
    {
        randomInt = 1 + rand.nextInt(100);
        numbers[counter] = randomInt;
        System.out.printf("Digit %d: %d \n", counter, numbers[counter]);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Have you defined rand?

Comment: For a non-static variable to be referenced, an instance of the enclosing class must be created first. Include the code where `rand` is declared in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a new `Random` class object named `rand` before using it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int length = 30;
    int numbers[] = new int[length];
    int randomInt;
    int counter;
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++)
    {
        randomInt = 1 + rand.nextInt(100);
        numbers[counter] = randomInt;
        System.out.printf("Digit %d: %d \n", counter, numbers[counter]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I actually had the "Random rand = new Random();"  line of code the problem though was that i had accidentally typed outside of the main method. Cheers!

Comment: No problem- make sure to mark the question as answered if all is working well now :)